# Unable to do switching from Rose to rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody, rational-rose

I am very very new to this rose/rhapsody model.
I have a .mdl file(belonging to rose) which I need to convert to Rhapsody.
For this I followed the below mentioned steps:

1. In IBM rational rhapsody from Tools menu I did a Import form rose->Import model and gave the .mdl file.
2. then from Tools menu I clicked on State Machine Export.

This gave me a .txt file. But when I compare this .txt with the one from Rose .txt, lot of differences are there.E.g. the name of state in rose is SUBSYSTEM_COMPLETE_SHUTDOWN  but in rhapsody it is terminationstate_3.

I am not getting any info regarding this in any website.
Need help for resolving this.

Thanks.